# Logistic Regression with time slices

Tags: logistic, survival

I'm using logistic regression to predict student retention in an online course.

I have a data of student interactions within a web platform of an online course. The course spans 6 weeks, with new lecture resources and new assignments uploaded at the beginning of each week. The weekly assignments due at the end of each week. Students can watch lecture videos, view/write forum posts, and do assignments. Students can drop out of the course any time (i.e. no longer interacting within the course platform).

Each week, I want to predict the likelihood of a student staying within the course in the next week (**stay in the next week=1, out in the next week=0**). The predictors are the number of times the student watch the lecture videos (**video_views**), the number of posts the student read (**posts_read**), the number of posts the student wrote (**post_written**) and the student's score of this week assignment (**score**).

I'm thinking of building 6 models using logistic regression, for each week. But I also want to make a connection between, say, week 6's model and week 5's model. Can such connection be shown if I use percentage of cumulative values for each predictors (e.g. cumulative number of assignment score out of total assignment score for the whole course) instead of weekly values?

Should I just build a single model with the course week (**course_week**) as another predictor? This is my first time using logistic regression, and I'm not sure about putting a time variable in a logistic regression model.

Comment: What you are doing, in essence, is discrete time survival analysis. [Here](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/mplus/seminars/DiscreteTimeSurvival/default.htm) is some information from UCLA's stats help site. I haven't seen these slideshows, but the UCLA site is of uniformly high-quality.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, gung. I've done a quick read on the UCLA's slides, and it seems their model measures the survival probability of a reference subject at any time based on several preconditions of that subject and an early observation.

Comment: The subjects in my model have no preconditions data (we don't have access to students' data other than students' interaction within the course), and the observations are happening weekly.

Am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Couldn't you use proportional odd logistic regression? Outcome is number of weeks "stayed in".